# App close event without resritcted Capability

Tags: c#, uwp

I have developed an app for the Microsoft store. The problem is, that I can not upload this app to the store, because I've used the confirmAppClose capability, to detect when my app gets closed.

Does anybody know another way to detect when my app gets closed?

Comment: Be sure to set the minimum required version high enough.  Build 15063 or higher required.

Comment: I've tried it in 1809 and 1803, but I still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know another way to detect when my app gets closed?

I am afraid there is no way to detect or prevent the app from exiting without using the `confirmAppClose` restricted capability. That's why it was introduced in the first place.

When it comes to [store submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-submission-options#publishing-hold-options?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077), you'll need to provide additional information on the Submission options page in order to receive approval for an app that uses a restricted capability.